# Can't Connect To A Wifi on 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, laptop

So few days ago i got a new Laptop with Ubuntu 13.10 installed on it. It works fine when i connect with wired ethernet, it even sees the wi-fi just when i double click it, it tries to connect and then it just stops with an empty wi-fi symbol. I'm very new to this whole system, so please try to simple the answers... Thank you. I'm really looking for a fix since having 2 cables at once is pretty annoying :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May problem with your wifi adaptor, frind a appropriate adaptor from your laptop manufacture, else [click here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported) for help.

Comment: I have Acer Aspire V5 and on their website, it says nothing about Linux drivers :( And here is the output from the help page tip: 04:00.1 SD Host controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader (rev 10) (prog-if 01)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0742
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
 Memory at 90400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci

Comment: It will have too many possible ways... try one by one with the link I gave you... and click the answer as correct.. Else get backup and reinstall the os by selecting every drivers....thank you...